# The given key was not present in the dictionary. error in mysql database c#

Tags: c#

I am creating a voting system. but this thing is not letting me move on to my project.

It says that

> "the given key was not present in the dictionary"

here is the code.
error says in `login = cmd.ExecuteReader();`

```
MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand();
cmd.CommandText = "Select * from candidate where StudentNumber = @student";
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@student", stuBox.Text);
cmd.Connection = connection;
MySqlDataReader login;
login = cmd.ExecuteReader();
```

Comment: have you opened `MySqlCommand`  anywhere?

Comment: Check you connection string to make sure you are connecting to  the correct database.  The candidate table does not have a column "student".

Comment: Can you share the connection string with sensitive data masked in it?

Answer (score 0):

It's happen when table not exist, column not available.

just verify your table

Or update below

cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@student", stuBox.string);

Answer (score 0):

Although the documentation states column names are [not case sensitive](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/identifier-case-sensitivity.html), I have indeed encountered peculiarities when querying MySQL from C# to do with incorrect table and column name casing.
I cannot explain the reason, but my suspicion it has to do with [server](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-general.html) and [connection](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-connection.html) collations and the way different client libraries handle it.

I would suggest you double check your table name and column exact spellings and use [backticks](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/23129/benefits-of-using-backtick-in-mysql-queries/23130) to quote all identifiers.